# Can I find the term depth via $node without resorting to a taxonomy_get_tree or an SQL query?

Tags: 6, taxonomy-terms

I'm trying to find all terms in a vocabulary associated with the current node, that do not have any children.

The most obvious way might be to use taxonomy_get_tree() and match with the returned array to find the childless. Another way is to use a function like [this one](http://drupal.org/node/886526), and it involves a MySQL query. While my current taxonomy is small and the performance concerns are minimal, I would like to avoid this if this info is already available somewhere.

So, how can I find the depth of a taxonomy term, in a more performance friendly way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The data for taxonomy is in the database. If you want to get that data there is no way to do so without running a database query.

Any function that retrieves this data (including `taxonomy_get_tree()` and the function you link to above) has to run database queries to get at the data.

`taxonomy_get_tree()` is a bit heavy so I'd advise using the `term_depth` function you link to. If you want to increase performance slightly you can improve that function to offer a static page load cache. This will only make a difference if you call the function more than once in a single page load though:

```
function term_depth($tid) {
  static $depths = array();

  if (!isset($depths[$tid])) {
    $parent = db_result(db_query("SELECT parent FROM {term_hierarchy} WHERE tid = %d", $tid));
    if ($parent == 0) {
      $depths[$tid] = 1;
    }
    else {
      $depths[$tid] = 1 + term_depth($parent);
    }
  }

  return $depths[$tid];
}
```

Short of building your own cache mechanism that doesn't rely on the database (which would be a massive amount of overkill for this situation) I don't see any way of making this more performant.

Comment: C'mon Drupal, it was just *one more* detail, aside from the fairly exhaustive data inside $node :( This would have made my life so much more easy!

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion on making it a static variable. That will indeed help the speed...

Answer (score 4):

Drupal 7 version of Clive's answer:

```
/**
 * Find the depth of a term
 */
function term_depth($tid) { 
  static $depths = array();

  if (!isset($depths[$tid])) { 
    $parent = db_select('taxonomy_term_hierarchy', 'th')
      ->fields('th', array('parent'))
      ->condition('tid', $tid)
      ->execute()->fetchField();

    if ($parent == 0) { 
      $depths[$tid] = 1;
    } 
    else { 
      $depths[$tid] = 1 + term_depth($parent);
    } 
  } 

  return $depths[$tid];
}
```